# How to spend bounties wisely?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I have crossed the 4000 rep points mark, giving me all the privileges available. Now I can become the big spender ;) As you might have noticed I have already experimented a bit with giving away some bounties.

But how do you spent bounties wisely? Any thoughts?

Comment: Buy Christmas gifts for the other contributors. Or a cappuccino machine for the chatroom.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to you really ;)

- Some people might save them for when they need to draw attention to a topic, or really want an answer.
- Sometimes you want to reward someone for an awesome answer, but which you aren't or can't accept as THE answer.
- Sometimes you're feeling flush and generous around Christmas and are throwing bounties around (See 6 active bounties at present!)

Point to remember: if you don't award them, they do expire, and then nobody gets the bounty - it doesn't come back to you.  So make sure to remember to actually award them!

Comment: I thought that they would go to the answer with the highest rep points. Good that you mention that this is not the case!

Comment: Oh, and congrats on reaching 4000!

Comment: @Andra, some of both actually.  Quoted directly from the FAQ: "If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created *after the bounty started* with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone."